# batch file put if inside for loop error

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, ms-dos

I have a working for loop to print all zip file's name under one working directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%i in (*.zip) do (
    echo %%i
    )
```

I have another working if block to check and print out a zip file size :

```
echo set FileSize=%%~z1 > %temp%\GetFileSize.bat
call %temp%\GetFileSize  "720P_1500K_101399042.zip"
if %FileSize% GTR 1000 (
    echo %FileSize% is greater than 1000
    ) else (
    echo %FileSize% is NOT greater than 1000
    )
```

Now, I am trying to combine these two pieces together to have a **for loop** to get all zip files under the working directory and at the same time use the **if block** to check the file size and then print out the size. But I was told: ***1000 was unexpected at this time.*** why?

```
for %%i in (*.zip) do (
    echo %%i
    echo set FileSize=%%~z1 > %temp%\GetFileSize.bat
    call %temp%\GetFileSize  "%%i"
    if %FileSize% GTR 1000 (
        echo %FileSize% is greater than 1000
    ) else (
        echo %FileSize% is NOT greater than 1000
    )
    )
```

Comment: technically, because `%filesize%` is not defined, so the `if` syntax is invalid. You'd need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: @Stephan you are right. if I replace all %FilesSize% with !FileSize!, the error goes away but the result is wrong. that is the actual file size is not used in the if block correctly.

Comment: it is used as you programmed it. The way you created the secondary batch file, added a space to the size, which forces `if` to string mode (where 2 is "greater" than 1000) (Note: this happens only with a delayed !variable! - with a "normal" %variable%, `if` can correct the additional space). Change to `(echo set FileSize=%%~z1) > %temp%\GetFileSize.bat` to avoid that space. Welcome to batch - the world of pain and headache.

Comment: @Stephan I added the bracket to the "echo set ..." line as your reply. The result is the same: a bigger file print out "... NOT greater than 1000"

Comment: run with `echo off` and see what's exactly executed (you should see the actual filesize) btw: you *did* `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` before *using*  delayed expansion, did you?)

Comment: @Stephan my bad, missing the "enabledelayedexpansion". It works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use powershell for this:

```
Get-ChildItem "Filepath" -Filter *.zip | ForEach {
  "$_.Name"
  If($_.Length -gt 1000){
    Write-Host "$($_.Length) is greater than 1000"
  }
  Else {
    Write-Host "$($_.Length) is NOT greater than 1000"
  }
}
```

Or if you strictly want to use batch, then why pass it to another batch file? Directly do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%i in (*.zip) do (
    echo %%i
    if %%~zi GTR 1000 (
        echo %%~zi is greater than 1000
    ) else (
        echo %%~zi is NOT greater than 1000
    )
)
```

Comment: @peterboston check the snippets now

Comment: thank you. it works now. I find inside the for loop I need to modify the file to get a new file, saying COPY /b something+"%%i" "%%~ni-new". how can I get the new file's size in the if block.

Comment: with another `for`loop: `for %%j in ("%%~ni-new") do set "newsize=%%~zj"`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan for the note.

Comment: @Stephan you are right, add another for loop does the trick. but cannot get the correct result if set "newsize=%%~zj" is used. I have to use %%~zj in the if condition directly

Comment: It's indeed better to use `%%~zj` directly, but when you really need it in a variable for any reason, see my first comment to your question.

Comment: @Stephan but the "delayed !variable!" doesn't get a correct result as I reported back to your comment on my original question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like:

- For to accept your arguments (`%1, %2, %3,  %n...`) and echoing name and size:

```batch-file
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not "%~x1" == ".zip" (
     set "_loops=*.zip" ) else set "_loops=%*" 
     
set^ "_bit=is greater" && for %%i in (!_loops!) do (
     if not %%~zi gtr 1000 set "_bit=!_bit: = NOT !"
     echo\File %%~nxi ^| Size %%~zi !_bit! than 1000
     set "_bit=is greater"
   )

endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

- Little more simple and with arguments too:

```batch-file
@echo off

if not "%~x1"==".zip" (
     set "_zip=*.zip") else set "_zip=%*" 
     
for %%i in (%_zip%)do if %%~zi gtr 1000 (
     echo\%%~zi is greater than 1000
     )else echo\%%~zi is NOT greater
```

- One option that only echoing name and size:

```batch-file
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set^ "_bit=is greater" &&  for %%i in ("*.zip") do (
     if not %%~zi gtr 1000 set "_bit=!_bit: = NOT !"
     echo\File %%~nxi ^| Size %%~zi !_bit! than 1000
     set "_bit=is greater"
   )

endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

---

- Copy file if is greater:

```batch-file
@echo off 

set "_bit=is greater"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   
for %%i in ("*.zip")do if %%~zi gtr 1000 (
   copy /b "file" + "%%~fi" "%%~dpni_new%%~xi" 2>nul 
   echo\File %%~nxi ^| Size %%~zi !_bit! than 1000 ) else ( 
   echo\File %%~nxi ^| Size %%~zi !_bit: = NOT ! than 1000 )

endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

- Copy file if is NOT greater:

```batch-file
@echo off

set "_bit=is greater"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in ("*.zip")do if %%~zi leq 1000 (
   copy /b "file" + "%%~fi" "%%~dpni_new%%~xi" 2>nul 
   echo\File %%~nxi ^| Size %%~zi !_bit: = NOT ! than 1000
   ) else ;echo\File %%~nxi ^| Size %%~zi !_bit! than 1000

endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

---

## For PowerShell

```batch-file
Get-Item "D:\Folder\*.zip"|foreach-object { if ($_.Length -gt 1000) 
  { Write-Host $_.Length is greater than 1000 } else { 
    Write-Host $_.Length is NOT greater than 1000 }}
```

- Or, with aliases:

```batch-file
 gi "D:\Folder\*.zip" | ? { if ( $_.Length -gt 1000 ) 
  { write-host $_.Length is greater than 1000 } else { 
     write-host $_.Length is NOT greater than 1000 } }
```